# How do I log OutOfMemoryError's in slf4j

Tags: akka, slf4j

I'm running an `slf4j` logger in an akka system. If the system runs low on memory, I get an `OutOfMemoryError` in the console. However, this does not show up in the log file. That makes these errors hard to spot since I have to notice them before they disappear off the top of the console. Is there a way to get them to show up in the log file too?

This is the error:

```
[error] (pool-21-thread-22) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
         ....
```

And this is my `logback.xml`, which I thought I'd set up to give exactly the same output in the log file vs the console:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%X{akkaSource}] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log/akka.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%X{akkaSource}] [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="slick" level="INFO">
  </logger>

  <logger name="myserver" level="DEBUG">
  </logger>

  <logger name="akka" level="DEBUG">
  </logger>

  <logger name="spray" level="DEBUG">
  </logger>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Most other errors are appearing in both the console and the logfile, but not the `OutOfMemoryError`'s. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Scalatra I got the OOM to show on logs by adding `error` to `MyServlet extending ScalatraServlet`:

```
error {
  case t: Throwable => {
    logger.error(s"Unexpected throwable: ${t.toString}", t)
    throw t
  }
}
```